# Access and using geometry nodes as functions in Python

Tags: python, scripting, geometry-nodes

How can I use the Geometry nodes graph in python or at least get access to one of its node functionality?

For example I want to use the Attribute Sample Texture Node along side editing vertex group values.

Comment: Hello, could you specify if you would want the node's behavior in a stand alone environment or if you would want to create a geo nodes modifier, and add a node setup which contains an attribute sample texture node ? I don't think you can do the former, while the latter is definitely possible

Comment: thanks for the comment,
instead of writing my own function, I wish i could access the node functionality from python and even better along side with bmesh.